# How to send scanned bar code to pc ( to html text box)?

Tags: php, android, barcode

I hope to develop a library management system online using php. So, I'd like to get ISBN code as an input.

What I need is to capture that ISBN code and paste into the text field to send it to server. I think this can be done using bar code scanner. Also, another thing is that I need to implement a way to send my captured code to my text field.

Is there any android application which fulfills my requirements? Any suggestions?

Thank you.

Comment: what bar code scanner do you have? (also, zxing works well if you use the camera for scanning barcodes, however, it is not clear what is your client app)

Comment: Use the ZXing library to use the bar code reading in your Android app: http://code.google.com/p/zxing/